# Angular test not failing but throwing 'Error during cleanup of component' TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, observable, karma-runner

My test suite are all passing but I have the following error being thrown:

`'Error during cleanup of component' TypeError: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of undefined`

It is really annoying more than anything else but I do not know how to remove it.

My component is written as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { User } from 'src/models/user';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-list',
  templateUrl: './user-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-list.component.scss']
})
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  users: Array<User> = [];
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private service: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.service.getUserList().subscribe(data => this.users = data.list.entries)
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  remove(id: string): Array<User>{
    return this.users = [...this.users].filter(user => user.entry.id !== id);
  }

}
```

Any the test spec:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list.component';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

describe('UserListComponent', () => {
  let component: UserListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserListComponent>;
  let userService: UserService;
  let el: DebugElement;
  let users: any = [{
    "entry": {
      "firstName": "Ryan",
      "id": "ryan",
      "enabled": false,
    }
  },
    {
      "entry": {
        "firstName": "Administrator",
        "id": "admin",
        "enabled": true,
      }
    }
  ];

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [UserListComponent],
      providers: [UserService],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, MatChipsModule, MatIconModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  })

  it('should create', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('load users OnInit', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(userService, 'getUserList').and.returnValue(of({
          list: {
            entries: users
          }
      }).pipe(delay(1)));

      fixture.detectChanges();

      expect(component.users).toEqual([]);
      expect(userService.getUserList).toHaveBeenCalled();

      tick(1);

      expect(component.users).toEqual(users);
  }));

  it('render the user list', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(userService, 'getUserList').and.returnValue(of({
          list: {
            entries: users
          }
      }).pipe(delay(1)));

      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick(1);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-chip-list'));
      expect(el).toBeDefined();
      expect(el.queryAll(By.css('mat-chip')).length).toEqual(2);
  }));

  it('should remove a user from the list', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(userService, 'getUserList').and.returnValue(of({
        list: {
          entries: users
        }
    }).pipe(delay(1)));
    spyOn(component, 'remove').and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick(1);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let removeIcons = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('mat-icon'));

    expect(removeIcons.length).toEqual(1);

    removeIcons[0].triggerEventHandler('click', {stopPropagation: function(){return false;}});

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.remove).toHaveBeenCalledWith('admin');
    expect(component.users.length).toEqual(1);

    let chips = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('mat-chip'));
    expect(chips.length).toEqual(1);
  }));

  it('should differentiate an "enabled" user', () => {
    component.users = users;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let chips = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mat-chip');
    component.users.forEach((user, index) => {
        expect(chips[index].classList.contains('mat-chip-with-trailing-icon')).toBe(user.entry.enabled ? true : false);
        expect(window.getComputedStyle(fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('mat-chip')[index]).backgroundColor).toBe(user.entry.enabled ? 'rgb(173, 255, 47)' : 'rgb(224, 224, 224)');
    });
  });

});
```

I understand that the issue is in the `ngOnDestroy` where we unsubscribe from the observable.  I tried wrapping `this.subscription.unsubscribe();` in a check for its definition but I was not happy to alter the application code to make the tests pass.

Some other solutions mentioned that adding `fixture.detectChanges();` in the first assertion `should create` would trigger `ngOnInit` but although the tests now pass the error remains.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have not subscribed in all the test cases and in that cases subscription is not formed yet.

So, it is better to check if subscription is formed or not before unsubscribe.

```
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
      if(subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE** - only change needed at test case end

As you are subscribing inside the ngOnInit, you need to make sure you provide it mock data before creating a component. Hope it will resolve your issue.

```
beforeEach(() => {
          spyOn(userService, 'getUserList').and.returnValue(of({
          list: {
            entries: users
          }
      }).pipe(delay(1)));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
  });
```

Comment: but that is my point, you are updating code to fix test errors. In which cases am I not subscribing?

Comment: i don't see problem with that, on the contrary, he is making the code more secure because subscriptions can be complete by so many ways.